# Why does "How do you want to open this file?" appear on some computers, not others

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

I have written a small windows forms utility in C# which ends up displaying a list of files (with various extensions) in a list box, and the user can double-click on one of the files and the program will attempt to open it by simply calling

```
Process.Start(outputFilesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

So far so good.

Now, on most of the Windows 10 boxes in the office, if there is no application registered for the selected file's extension then windows automatically puts up the "How do you want to open this file?" dialog, which is fine - the user can pick an application - no further work required from me.

However, one of my colleagues complained that, rather than opening this dialog, the program threw an exception "No application is associated with the specified file for this application".

The Web is filled with articles on how to *stop* the "How do you want to open this file?" dialog appearing, but I can't find anything that tells me why it would appear on some computers but not others, and how to ensure that it always *does* appear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use [AssocQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-assocquerystringw) to verify whether an association exists and create a prompt yourself, when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was possibly [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/1366302/windows-10-wont-let-me-set-default-apps-for-file-extensions) over on the superuser site.

The gist of it comes down to the following KB article for a patch that fixes a known issue.

> Windows 10 patch
>   [KB4467682](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4467682/windows-10-update-kb4467682)
>
> > Addresses an issue that prevents some users from setting Win32 program defaults for certain app and file type combinations using the
> >     Open with… command or Settings > Apps > Default apps.

Comment: KB4467682 seems to address a problem which prevents the user from setting default apps for certain file extensions. My problem is not whether or not a default can be set, but the way windows reacts when a default application is not set. Also, I do not seem to have KB4467682 installed and neither does my colleague. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @Dave It represents a problem that *some* users experience. Not having this patch does not mean you will experience the problem. However, depending upon the configuration, your colleague could be experiencing this exact issue. If they cannot set a default program for a file type, they may never see the screen for it and the OS simply gives them the error they are seeing.

Comment: Fair enough. As it's a recent KB (and not a serious problem) I'll ask my colleague to see if the problem goes away following the next Windows update. I'll flag as answered in the meantime. Thanks